# pgfplots: Reducing Marker Size

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Do you know how can I reduce the size of the markers?

code:

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{contour}




\usepackage{bm}        
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
%\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}


\usetikzlibrary{%
    arrows,%
    calc,%
    arrows.meta,
    fit,%
    patterns,%
    plotmarks,%
    shadows,
    shapes.geometric,%
    shapes.misc,%
    shapes.symbols,%
    shapes.arrows,%
    shapes.callouts,%
    shapes.multipart,%
    shapes.gates.logic.US,%
    shapes.gates.logic.IEC,%
    er,%
    automata,%
    backgrounds,%
    chains,%
    topaths,%
    trees,%
    petri,%
    mindmap,%
    matrix,%
    % calendar,%
    folding,%
    fadings,%
    through,%
    positioning,%
    scopes,%
    decorations.fractals,%
    decorations.shapes,%
    decorations.text,%
    decorations.pathmorphing,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,%
    decorations.footprints,%
    decorations.markings,%
    shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,positioning,calc}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
        width=\linewidth,
        line width=0.5,
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        tick label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}},
        label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend image post style={},
        grid style={white},
        xlabel={Epochs},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2
        },
        legend style={at={(1,0.95)}, anchor=north east, line width=.3pt,mark size=.4pt, draw=none, fill=none}
        ]
        \addplot[yellow!85!black,mark=diamond*] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
        1.1256
        0.9999
        0.9737
        0.9623
        0.9558
        0.9517
        0.9487
        0.9465
        0.9451
        0.9439
        0.943
        0.9425
        0.9416
        0.9411
        0.941
        0.9403
        0.9401
        0.94
        0.9403
        0.9395
        0.94
        0.94
        0.9392
        0.9395
        0.9391
        0.9399
        0.9394
        0.9396
        0.9394
        0.9393
        0.939
        0.939
        0.9392
        0.9393
        0.9389
        0.939
        0.9389
        0.9393
        0.9396
        0.9391
        0.9393
        0.939
        0.9387
        0.9394
        0.9392
        0.9393
        0.9396
        0.939
        0.9388
        0.9392


        };
        \addlegendentry{Test error} 

        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}

        \subcaption{ 100K}
        \label{fig:sub11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
        width=\linewidth,
        line width=0.5,
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        tick label style={font={\tiny}},
        legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}},
        label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend image post style={},
        grid style={white},
        xlabel={Epochs},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2
        },
        legend style={at={(1,0.95)}, anchor=north east,  draw=none, fill=none},
        ]
        \addplot[blue,mark=*] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
            1.1171
            0.9368
            0.9208
            0.9154
            0.9128
            0.9116
            0.9105
            0.9098
            0.9096
            0.9094
            0.909
            0.9092
            0.909
            0.9089
            0.9087
            0.9088
            0.909
            0.909
            0.9085
            0.9088
            0.9086
            0.9087
            0.9086
            0.9088
            0.9087
            0.9088
            0.9087
            0.9089
            0.9087
            0.9086
            0.9087
            0.9086
            0.9088
            0.9088
            0.9086
            0.9087
            0.9088
            0.9087
            0.9088
            0.9086
            0.9089
            0.9088
            0.9087
            0.9088
            0.9088
            0.9087
            0.9089
            0.9088
            0.9089
            0.9087




        };
        \addlegendentry{Test} 

        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}


        \subcaption{1M}
        \label{fig:sub22}

    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Performance.}
    \label{tablex}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have `mark size`

Comment: Mmm yeah, but it does not change anything. I don't know what's going on

Comment: Remark: It's your 26th question: Next time please reduce the code to the minimal necessary amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mark size` do this. Here I set `mark size` to `1pt`, you may need a bigger number.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{contour}




\usepackage{bm}        
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
%\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}


\usetikzlibrary{%
    arrows,%
    calc,%
    arrows.meta,
    fit,%
    patterns,%
    plotmarks,%
    shadows,
    shapes.geometric,%
    shapes.misc,%
    shapes.symbols,%
    shapes.arrows,%
    shapes.callouts,%
    shapes.multipart,%
    shapes.gates.logic.US,%
    shapes.gates.logic.IEC,%
    er,%
    automata,%
    backgrounds,%
    chains,%
    topaths,%
    trees,%
    petri,%
    mindmap,%
    matrix,%
    % calendar,%
    folding,%
    fadings,%
    through,%
    positioning,%
    scopes,%
    decorations.fractals,%
    decorations.shapes,%
    decorations.text,%
    decorations.pathmorphing,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,%
    decorations.footprints,%
    decorations.markings,%
    shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,positioning,calc}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
        width=\linewidth,
        line width=0.5,
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        tick label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}},
        label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend image post style={},
        grid style={white},
        xlabel={Epochs},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2
        },
        legend style={at={(1,0.95)}, anchor=north east, line width=.3pt,mark size=.4pt, draw=none, fill=none}
        ]
        \addplot[yellow!85!black,mark=diamond*,mark size=1pt] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
        1.1256
        0.9999
        0.9737
        0.9623
        0.9558
        0.9517
        0.9487
        0.9465
        0.9451
        0.9439
        0.943
        0.9425
        0.9416
        0.9411
        0.941
        0.9403
        0.9401
        0.94
        0.9403
        0.9395
        0.94
        0.94
        0.9392
        0.9395
        0.9391
        0.9399
        0.9394
        0.9396
        0.9394
        0.9393
        0.939
        0.939
        0.9392
        0.9393
        0.9389
        0.939
        0.9389
        0.9393
        0.9396
        0.9391
        0.9393
        0.939
        0.9387
        0.9394
        0.9392
        0.9393
        0.9396
        0.939
        0.9388
        0.9392


        };
        \addlegendentry{Test error} 

        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}

        \subcaption{ 100K}
        \label{fig:sub11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
        width=\linewidth,
        line width=0.5,
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        tick label style={font={\tiny}},
        legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}},
        label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend image post style={},
        grid style={white},
        xlabel={Epochs},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2
        },
        legend style={at={(1,0.95)}, anchor=north east,  draw=none, fill=none},
        ]
        \addplot[blue,mark=*,mark size=1pt] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
            1.1171
            0.9368
            0.9208
            0.9154
            0.9128
            0.9116
            0.9105
            0.9098
            0.9096
            0.9094
            0.909
            0.9092
            0.909
            0.9089
            0.9087
            0.9088
            0.909
            0.909
            0.9085
            0.9088
            0.9086
            0.9087
            0.9086
            0.9088
            0.9087
            0.9088
            0.9087
            0.9089
            0.9087
            0.9086
            0.9087
            0.9086
            0.9088
            0.9088
            0.9086
            0.9087
            0.9088
            0.9087
            0.9088
            0.9086
            0.9089
            0.9088
            0.9087
            0.9088
            0.9088
            0.9087
            0.9089
            0.9088
            0.9089
            0.9087




        };
        \addlegendentry{Test} 

        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}


        \subcaption{1M}
        \label{fig:sub22}

    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Performance.}
    \label{tablex}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

But my sugestion is: not to use a marker at all...

Comment: We answered at the same time :).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, that I get it because you already had the solution in your code (wrong position)?!

Just add `mark size = 0.4pt` to your `\addplot` command: `\addplot[mark = diamond*, mark size = 0.4pt]`

Comment: We posted at the same time :) but I don't think `mark size` is in his code

Comment: @JouleV It's in the code for the `legend style`.